# ORDER of UNION with subselects

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

I am just playing around with some code here, and trying to make a spreadsheet of information instead of trying to look through multiple rows and columns, but my union is putting it a wrong order

```
DECLARE 
    @ini VARCHAR(20),
    @inid VARCHAR(20)
SET @ini = 'I2005-000054'
SET @inid = (SELECT INCIDENT_ID FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini)

SELECT
    '>> Incident # <<' AS '-', @ini AS '-', 
    '>> Incident ID <<' AS '-', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),INCIDENT_ID) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) AS '-', 
    '>> Call Type <<' AS '-', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CALL_TYPE_ID) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini)+ ' : ' +(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM CALL_TYPE ct INNER JOIN INCIDENT i on ct.CALL_TYPE_ID = i.CALL_TYPE_ID AND i.INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) AS '-',
    '>> Final Call Type <<' AS '-', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),FINAL_CALL_TYPE_ID) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini)+ ' : ' +(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM CALL_TYPE ct INNER JOIN INCIDENT i on ct.CALL_TYPE_ID = i.FINAL_CALL_TYPE_ID AND i.INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) AS '-',
    '>> Initial Narrative <<' AS '-', ISNULL((SELECT INITIAL_NARRATIVE FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini),'') AS '-'
UNION
SELECT
    '>> Call Time <<' , (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CALL_TIME, 121) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) , 
    '>> Create Date <<' , (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CREATE_DATE, 121) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) , 
    '>> Street Name <<', ISNULL((SELECT CC_FULL_DISPATCH_LOCATION FROM DISPATCH_LOCATION WHERE INCIDENT_ID = @inid), ''),
    '','',
    '',''
```

The sample I am trying to achieve is

```
>> Incident # << | ### | >> Incident ID << | ### | >> Call Type <<   | ### | etc...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> Call Time <<  | ### | >> Create Date << | ### | >> Street Name << | ### | etc...
```

But it comes out reversed

```
>> Call Time <<  | ### | >> Create Date << | ### | >> Street Name << | ### | etc...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> Incident # << | ### | >> Incident ID << | ### | >> Call Type <<   | ### | etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results of a query in a particular order, then you need to use `order by`.

So, your query should be:

```
SELECT 1 as which,
    '>> Incident # <<' AS '-', @ini AS '-', 
    '>> Incident ID <<' AS '-', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),INCIDENT_ID) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) AS '-', 
    '>> Call Type <<' AS '-', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CALL_TYPE_ID) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini)+ ' : ' +(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM CALL_TYPE ct INNER JOIN INCIDENT i on ct.CALL_TYPE_ID = i.CALL_TYPE_ID AND i.INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) AS '-',
    '>> Final Call Type <<' AS '-', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),FINAL_CALL_TYPE_ID) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini)+ ' : ' +(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM CALL_TYPE ct INNER JOIN INCIDENT i on ct.CALL_TYPE_ID = i.FINAL_CALL_TYPE_ID AND i.INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) AS '-',
    '>> Initial Narrative <<' AS '-', ISNULL((SELECT INITIAL_NARRATIVE FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini),'') AS '-'
UNION
SELECT 2 as which,
    '>> Call Time <<' , (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CALL_TIME, 121) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) , 
    '>> Create Date <<' , (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CREATE_DATE, 121) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCIDENT_NUMBER = @ini) , 
    '>> Street Name <<', ISNULL((SELECT CC_FULL_DISPATCH_LOCATION FROM DISPATCH_LOCATION WHERE INCIDENT_ID = @inid), ''),
    '','',
    '',''
ORDER BY which;
```

In particular, `union` removes duplicates so it does change the ordering.  In SQL Server, `union all` would probably do what you want -- but there is *no* guarantee.  However, in execution plans that I've seen, the `union all` operator reads from the first input until it is exhausted and then moves to the next, and so on.  This is undocumented, so you should not depend on it, but it does seem to be how the engine behaves.